# Golang Postgres pq failed scanning to *string

Tags: postgresql, go, squirrel-sql

I'm trying to scan a postgresql list into an empty slice of string. However, I'm getting the error below:
`Failed creating education: sql: Scan error on column index 14, name "descriptions": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type string into type *[]*string`. Looks like I need to customize the scanner somehow, but how do I do that with squirrel? thanks.

Here's how I'm building the query:

```
squirrel.StatementBuilder.PlaceholderFormat(squirrel.Dollar).RunWith(db).Insert("educations").
        Columns("id", "school", "city", "state", "degree", "month_start", "year_start", "month_end", "year_end", "\"order\"", "logo_url", "created_at", "updated_at", "style", "descriptions").
        Values(
            uuid.Must(uuid.NewV4()).String(),
            education.School,
            education.City,
            education.State,
            education.Degree,
            education.MonthStart,
            education.YearStart,
            education.MonthEnd,
            education.YearEnd,
            education.Order,
            education.LogoURL,
            currentTime,
            currentTime,
            savedStyle.ID,
            pq.Array(education.Descriptions),
        ).
        Suffix("RETURNING *").
        Scan(
            &savedEducation.ID,
            &savedEducation.School,
            &savedEducation.City,
            &savedEducation.State,
            &savedEducation.Degree,
            &savedEducation.MonthStart,
            &savedEducation.YearStart,
            &savedEducation.MonthEnd,
            &savedEducation.YearEnd,
            &savedEducation.Order,
            &savedEducation.LogoURL,
            &savedEducation.CreatedAt,
            &savedEducation.UpdatedAt,
            &ignored,
            &savedEducation.Descriptions,
        )
```

Comment: Change last scan argument to  `pq.Array(&education.Descriptions)`.

Comment: I've tried that, got a different errors saying `Failed creating education: sql: Scan error on column index 14, name "descriptions": pq: parsing array element index 0: pq: scanning to *string is not implemented; only sql.Scanner`

Comment: For scanner `[]string` is allowed `[]*string` may not  allowed

Comment: If the description field is nullable in your table, you should use `sql.NullString` instead of `string`. https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullString

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `pq.StringArray` type for the field `savedEducation.Descriptions`.  This is a `[]string` with the additional `Value()` and `Scan()` methods provided by the pq library.